# Confusion about es + sich + in/ins

Tags: difference, reflexive

I have come across various sentences that I think have different meanings, but I cannot quite grasp which means what. I am talking about sentences such as

- Er hat das Bett gemacht.
- Er hat sich das Bett gemacht.
- Er hat es sich ins Bett gemacht.
- Er hat es sich im Bett gemacht.
- Er hat es im Bett gemacht.
- Er hat ins Bett gemacht.
- Er hat im Bett gemacht.

I am totally confused; I first thought these all mean "He went to bed.", but I got some strange looks when I told contacts (about my colleague and myself) something like "Wir haben es gestern um 10 im Bett gemacht." or "Wir haben gestern um 10 ins Bett gemacht.", so I thought I'd ask here how to distinguish which means which.

Comment: Did you try checking a dictionary for different meanings/translations? Because **none** of these mean *he went to bed.*

Comment: Also, welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Visit the [help] for any unanswered questions on how it works.

Answer (score 5):

> Er hat das Bett gemacht.
>
> Er hat sich das Bett gemacht.

He made (himself) the bed. (Meaning, he made the bed look nice for the day.)

> Er hat es sich ins Bett gemacht.
>
> Er hat ins Bett gemacht.

He peed into the bed. (the phrase with "sich" is not correct but has the same meaning.)

> Er hat es im Bett gemacht.

He had sex in the bed.

> Er hat es sich im Bett gemacht.

He made sex to himself in the bed.

> Er hat im Bett gemacht.

That one misses **what** he had made in the bed. As the options what to do in bed besides sleeping are quite limited, this one leads to one of the thoughts above.

> Wir haben es gestern um 10 im Bett gemacht.

We had sex in bed yesterday at 10:00. (Wow! You are really German, having sex by the clock!)

> Wir haben gestern um 10 ins Bett gemacht.

We peed into the bed yesterday at 10:00. (Well, that's some real ill fetish you have there.)

Conclusion: **Better avoid to talk about beds.**

Comment: I can't see the meaning of peeing in the bed in this sentence: "Er hat es sich ins Bett gemacht." I would just say it is completely wrong and has no meaning.

Comment: +1 for "Conclusion: Better avoid to talk about beds." ;)

Comment: @Iris: I know sloppy speakers who drop in *es sich* whereever it doesn't fit, so I subsumed it do be the same as without it. *Ins Bett/in die Hose machen* is a fixed phrase for peeing into your bed, your trousers etc. Consider *Er hat **sich** in die Hose gemacht.* In that latter sentence, with **sich** is more common use than without.

Comment: To leave out a "es sich" is not sloppy but just wrong (and as a native German I would never just leave out a Reflexivpronomen....)

Comment: That's why I've written above that sentence is not correct. And yes, people say things that aren't correct by the book. About *Er hat sich in die Hose gemacht* vs. *Er hat in die Hose gemacht*, I think they are both used frequently.

Comment: in this example both are correct http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Hose. However, "sich (vor Angst) in die Hose machen" is an idiom for _being very afraid_.